# Is there a way to extract "hidden data" from a text file that was used to create a pivot in an excel file using python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel file which contains a pivot that was created on a text file, and the raw data does not appear in any sheet naturally.

Manually it is quite simple, you just double click a pivot cell and it will automatically generate a new sheet containing the raw data the pivot is based on.

Now, I have looked practically everywhere with no success of finding out how to perform this automatically - all I need is a python access to the "hidden data" behind the pivot.

I might have used wrong keywords due to lack of excel knowledge, any guidance regarding this matter will be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

extending openpyxl [example](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pivot.html#example)

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.pivot.fields import Missing

wb = load_workbook("your_excel_file.xlsx")
ws = wb["your_pivot_sheetname"]
pivot_table = ws._pivots[0] # any will do as they share the same cache

## only get column names that are fields in the original table (database)
columns = [cf.name for cf in pivot_table.cache.cacheFields if cf.databaseField]
## list of all records 
rec_fields = [rec._fields for rec in pivot_table.cache.records.r]
## tuple of each field value or None if field missing value for each record
data = [tuple([field.v if type(field) != Missing else None for field in field_list]) 
        for field_list in rec_fields]


df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)
```